# How to calculate coverage probability from binomial confidence intervals?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, python, binomial-distribution, coverage-probability

For a given alpha I have been calculating various confidence intervals for a binomial distribution(Wald, Wilson, Agrest-Coulla etc.):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

def walds_trial(n, alpha):
    X = sum(np.random.binomial(1, 1/2, size=n))
    p_n_hat = X/n
    z_alpha_half = scipy.stats.norm.ppf(1-(alpha/2))
    upper = p_n_hat + z_alpha_half * np.sqrt((p_n_hat*(1-p_n_hat))/n)
    lower = p_n_hat - z_alpha_half * np.sqrt((p_n_hat*(1-p_n_hat))/n)
    return (upper, lower)

>> walds_trial(100,0.05)
(0.5979981992270027, 0.4020018007729973)
```

Basically what this `statsmodels` [function does](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint.html) or [this one](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.binom_conf_interval.html) in `astropy`.

However, I don't need the upper/lower bounds of the confidence interval though, **but a coverage probability**. What do I have to calculate to obtain that? What needs to be tweaked?

[R version](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/binom/versions/1.1-1/topics/binom.coverage) does exactly what I need - you don't get confidence intervals but coverage probability. I would like to use Python though.

Comment: Just do MC trials and check the coverage? Is that what is implemented in R?

Comment: How would that MC trial look like? I'd draw $n$ samples from $B(1, 1/2)$, calculate p_n_hat = sum of my samples / n and see if it is in the interval? How many times should I repeat that operation?

Comment: No you’d count whether the true value p was inside the confidence interval. Ironically though I’ve just realised I’m proposing another set of binomial trials :D

Comment: just read the source code..https://rdrr.io/cran/binom/src/R/binom.coverage.R .. basically its quite a brutal way.. calculate ci for all x all methods and merge them

Comment: do you really need that? I can try to translate the R code to python but you might be better off using rpy2 for instance lol

Comment: I just translated the R code myself, thank you for the idea. :)

Comment: @НикитаВасильев if you solve the problem, you can answer your own question