# Calculating Bayesian Coverage Probabilities

Tags: r, probability, bayesian, confidence-interval

I am trying to learn how to calculate Bayesian Coverage Probabilities for the parameter from a Binomial Distribution using a Beta Distribution as a Prior.

As I understand, this would go as follows (fix values of alpha and beta):

- Step 1: Assume a true value of "p" and simulate data points from a Binomial Distribution with this "p"
- Step 2: Find an expression for the Posterior Distribution of "p" (there will be a closed form solution due to the Conjugacy)
- Step 3: Find out the 95% Credible Interval and see if the true value of "p" is contained within this interval
- Step 4: Repeat Step 1 - 3 many times
- Step 5: Choose a new true value of "p" and repeat Step 1 - Step 4

Here is my attempt to implement this in R:

```
# Set the values of p to loop through
prop = seq(0.0, 1, by = 0.005) 

# Initialize empty list to store results
my_list_2 = list()

# Start loop
for (j in 1:length(prop))  {
  p_j = prop[j]
  
  # Initialize empty list to store results for each iteration of the inner loop
  my_list = list()
  
  
  for (i in 1:1000) {
    sample_i = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = p_j)
    alpha_post = sum(sample_i) + 2
    beta_post = 100 - sum(sample_i) + 2
    posterior_sample = rbeta(1, alpha_post, beta_post)
    
    lower_i = qbeta(0.025, alpha_post, beta_post)
    upper_i = qbeta(0.975, alpha_post, beta_post)
    
    counter_i = ifelse(p_j >= lower_i && p_j <= upper_i, 1,0)
    
    a_i = data.frame(id = i, lower = lower_i, upper = upper_i, mean = posterior_sample, counter = counter_i)

    my_list[[i]] = a_i
  }
  
  # Bind data frames in my_list into a single data frame
  mean_i = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)
  
  # Calculate mean of counter column
  mean_counter = mean(mean_i$counter)
  
  # Create data frame b_j
  b_j = data.frame(id = j, p = p_j , mean = mean_counter)
  my_list_2[[j]] = b_j
print(b_j)
}

# Bind data frames in my_list_2 into a single data frame
result = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list_2)


plot(result$p, result$mean, type = "b", main = "95% Coverage Probability Plot Using Bayesian Credible Intervals", xlab = "Proportion Value", ylab = "Average Coverage Probability (95% Credible Interval)")
abline(h = mean(result$mean), col = "green", lty = 3)
abline(h = 0.95, col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

**Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?**

Thanks!

Comment: "Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?" I think most of us are probably more familiar with the plot that a Beta(0.5,0.5) prior gives; would you mind showing us the plot produced when you replace the "+2" on lines where alpha_post and beta_post are calculated with "+0.5"?

Comment: This seems to be a code review request in large part. See [How to calculate coverage probability from binomial confidence intervals?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466832/how-to-calculate-coverage-probability-from-binomial-confidence-intervals) and the [binom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/binom/index.html) package, which can compute the coverage for various binomial CIs including the Bayesian CI with beta prior.

Comment: The 95% credible interval is not the 95% HPD region which explains for the poor performances at 0 and 1.

Comment: @ John Madden: Thank you for your reply! I will add this to the question

Comment: @  Xi'an: Thank you for your reply! So the code I wrote is calculating the coverage probability of the 95% HPD Region and not the 95% Credible Interval?

Comment: @ dipetkov: I will check this out - thank you. I have a feeling that what I have done is not quite correct?